# Why does the cursor advance to the next character?

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-motions

I have `nnoremap Y y$` in my `.vimrc`.
If I type `"*y$`, my cursor stays in the same spot on a word. However if I type, `"*Y`, the cursor is advanced one character. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally it should not. But maybe your mapping has trailing space or something like that.

Comment: I never thought to turn on hidden characters and check that - you were absolutely right. Thanks.